# Cascaded Drop down is not working

Tags: jquery, dropdown, newform, cascading, sharepoint-list

I am using sharepoint lists New Form I have Added

```
       <script type="text/javascript" >
        $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({

        relationshipList: "Designation", //ChildList Name<br/>

        relationshipListParentColumn: "Department1", //Parent Name in ChildList<br/>

        relationshipListChildColumn: "Designation",  //Child Name in ChildList<br/>
        parentColumn: "Departments", //MainList Parent column Name<br/>
        childColumn: "Designation", ////MainList Child column Name<br/>
        debug: true <br/>
        })<br/>
    </script><br/>
```

I have No Error
but Cascaded is Not Working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I was missing $(document).ready(function(){
       
   });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code for cascading drop down.. below code also does not require SP Services reference, it is based on rest api...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
HillbillyCascade({
        parentFormField: "State", //Display name on form of field from parent list
        childList: "Cities", //List name of child list
        childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
        childFormField: "City", //Display name on form of the child field
        parentFieldInChildList: "State" //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
    });

});

function HillbillyCascade(params)
{

    var parent = $("select[Title='"+params.parentFormField+"'], select[Title='"+
        params.parentFormField+" Required Field']");

    $(parent).change(function(){
        DoHillbillyCascade(this.value,params);        
    });

    var currentParent = $(parent).val();
    if (currentParent != 0)        
    {
        DoHillbillyCascade(currentParent,params);
    }

}


function DoHillbillyCascade(parentID,params)
{

    var child = $("select[Title='"+params.childFormField+"'], select[Title='"+
        params.childFormField+" Required Field']," +
       "select[Title='"+params.childFormField+" possible values']");

    $(child).empty();

    var options = "";

    var call = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+params.childList+
            "')/items?$select=Id,"+params.childLookupField+","+params.parentFieldInChildList+
            "/Id&$expand="+params.parentFieldInChildList+"/Id&$filter="+params.parentFieldInChildList+
            "/Id eq "+ parentID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }

    });
    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){

        for (index in data.d.results)
        {
            options += "<option value='"+ data.d.results[index].Id +"'>"+
                data.d.results[index][params.childLookupField]+"</option>";
        }
        $(child).append(options);

    });
    call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        alert("Error retrieving information from list: " + params.childList + jqXHR.responseText);
        $(child).append(options);
    });

}
</script>
```

Source : [Cascading Drop Down Lists in SharePoint / Office 365 using REST](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/)